# Delphi : how to completely remove String from the memory

Tags: string, delphi, memory, encryption

```
Var
S1:String;
S2:String;
begin
   S1:='Sensitive Data';
   S2:=Crypt(S1,'encryption key');
   S1:='';
   FreeAndNil(S1);
end;
```

now when i search on my process memory using programs like "WinHex" i can easly find the un-crypted String !
even i tried to make new form to encrypt this string then unload the form but it still exist

is there any way to completely remove it

thanks in advance

Comment: All string literals will always remain in memory, so if you use string literals in your test project but get user input in your real code, your tests will fail.

Comment: How will it help if you remove the string from memory? It's already in the executable.

Comment: Once you finished working with sensitive data, overwrite it. And yes, secure environment instead.

Comment: Why are you calling Free on a string? You need to understand better.

Comment: If you're hard-coding this in encrypt it and hard code the encrypted value. The string will be plainly visible in memory and in the executable otherwise. Keep in mind someone with the right tools can stop your program when it is decrypted and read the key. Open a hex editor and search your EXE for the string--you'll see it obviously. If you encrypt it OUTSIDE the source then the encrypted string will be visible. This isn't a secure method but it does make someone work to actually find the key.

Comment: thx for all comments
i grab my string throw connection so its originally not stored in the executable file and its not 100% secured but i just wanna make it harder

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to overwrite the string with zeros when you are done with it. Like this:

```
ZeroMemory(Pointer(s), Length(s)*SizeOf(Char));
```

If you are paranoid that the compiler will optimise away the ZeroMemory then you could use SecureZeroMemory. However, the Delphi compiler will not optimise away ZeroMemory so this is somewhat moot.

If you just write:

```
s := '';
```

then the memory will be returned as is to the memory manager. You then have no control over when, if ever, the memory manager re-uses or returns the memory.

Obviously you'd need to do that to all copies of the string, and so the only sane approach is not to make copies of sensitive data.

None of this will help with the code as per your question because your sensitive data is a string literal and so is stored in the executable. This approach can only be applied meaningfully for dynamic data. I presume that your real program does not put sensitive data in literals.

Oh, and don't ever pass a string to FreeAndNil. You can only pass object variables to FreeAndNil, but the procedure uses an untyped var parameter so the compiler cannot save you from your mistake.

Comment: thx that's exactly what i'm talking about :)

Comment: The compiler could decide to optimize that away? Perhaps surround that by optimize off statement like SecureZeroMemory in win api does (and as implemented in jedi apilib)

Answer (score 5):

```
Var
  S1:String;
  S2:String;
begin
   S1:='Sensitive Data';
   S2:=Crypt(S1,'encryption key');
   UniqueString(S1); // <-- if reference count of S1 is not 1
   ZeroMemory(Pointer(S1), Length(S1)*SizeOf(Char));
   // or better: SecureZeroMemory(Pointer(S1), Length(S1)*SizeOf(Char));
   S1:='';
end;
```

Comment: Should we ensure that S1 is passed to Crypt by reference only?

Comment: @MarcusAdams: it does not matter in this case, since strings are reference counted, so it it still the same memory block one way or another..

Comment: It should be noted that your as presented, and David's code above you, will crash. The string `S1` is located in a read-only page in the process's address space. You're better to have a `BurnString` method, that takes the string by reference, and calls `System.UniqueString`. That way you don't have to worry about those "constant" strings with a secret reference count of zero.

Comment: @IanBoyd: presumably `'Sensitive Data'` and `'encryption key'` are not *actual* literals in the user's production code, but are obtained dynamically at runtime, from user input, loading a key file, etc. Crash aside, that would be a big security risk if they were *actual* literals, as Daniel Chapman commented earlier.

Comment: You are absolutely right. Just pointing out that a single function call, which in the 99.99% case turns into a no-op can stop a strange crash (say, for example, you have a unit test making sure that the string that you start with matches the string you end up with)